# Linked Sales Navigator Login issue in salesforce

Tags: linkedin

I did the configuration for linkedIn Sales Navigator and Salesforce. I am able to see Member and Company Information in LinkedIn widget embedded in Contact Layout too while I am logged in using LinkedIn Credentials on my system. The problem arises when I logged out of LinkedIn on my PC and check LinkedIn widget in salesforce. It's again asking for login as in attached Image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is facing same issue, Just want to add that I contacted LinkedIn support and confirmed that it is expected behaviour. Cheers!